# Protected react component Higher Order Component or not?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have written this HOC to protect certain areas/routes in my react app

```
import React from "react"

export default (WrappedComponent, AuthenticateComponent) => {
  let Protected = (props) => (
    props.authenticated
    ? <WrappedComponent {...props}/>
    : <AuthenticateComponent {...props}/>
  )
  return Protected
}
```

The only route component that uses this is `/account`

```
import React from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"

import Protected from "../components/Protected"
import LoginContainer from "./LoginContainer"

let AccountContainer = ({children}) => (
  React.Children.only(children)
)
export default connect(state => state.account)(Protected(AccountContainer, LoginContainer))
```

But the more I look at this, the more I think this could be solved without using a HOC by simply rewriting `AccountContainer` like this:

#### 1. By directly embedding the Protected code into the AccountContainer

```
let AccountContainer = (props) => (
  props.authenticated
  ? <WrappedComponent {...props}/>
  : <AuthenticateComponent {...props}/>
)
```

#### 2. Or the Protected component could be rewritten

```
let Protected = (props) => (
  props.authenticated
  ? <props.protectedContent {...props}/>
  : <props.authenticateComponent {...props}/>
)
```

#### 3. or like with letting the child components decide the flow

```
let Protected = (props) => (
  props.authenticated
  ? Child.renderOnly(props.children[0], {...props})/>
  : Child.renderOnly(props.children[1], {...props})/>
)
```

and used like this:

```
render() {
  <Protected authenticated={this.props.authenticated}>
    <ProfilePage/>
    <LoginPage/>
  </Protected>
}
```

I a HOC the way to go here (re-usability)?

Comment: Do you use react-router in your project?

Comment: yes, I do. The Protected component is basically the /account Route

Comment: I solved similar use case with react-router's `onEnter` functionality. It let's you intercept and change (navigate away to `/login` mayber) from current route. More info here https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback

Comment: I read about onEnter that it can have race conditions. Also, a redirect to /login is not really needed. Just render the login component. Works very well.

I see no reason to navigate to a login route, and losing context *why* the user was routed there. In the inline approach you can still display the part of the protected component that says "In order to see this you have to login".